# Problemas com ireport

Tags: primefaces, ireport

Estou tentando gerar um simples relatório, com três filtros: datainicial, datafinal e reservatório. O problema é que ao clicar no botão para gerar o relatório nada acontece, e não recebo mensagem alguma no console. Já coloquei prints e vi que o método esta sendo chamado.
Também notei que quando retiro os filtros do método o meu relatório em pdf é gerado tranquilamente.
Seguem os códigos.
xhtml:

```
                <h:form id="formGrid">
                Data Inicial: <p:calendar id="popup" value="#{relatorioHistoricoMB.dataInicial}" />
                Data Final: <p:calendar id="popup2" value="#{relatorioHistoricoMB.dataFinal}" />
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{relatorioHistoricoMB.reservatorio.idReservatorio}"
                    style="width:170px" required="true"
                    requiredMessage="Selecione algum.">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione o Reservatório" itemValue="0" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{relatorioHistoricoMB.listaReservatorio}"
                        var="reservatorio" itemLabel="#{reservatorio.nomeReservatorio}"
                        itemValue="#{reservatorio.idReservatorio}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:commandButton value="Gerar relatório" update="formGrid"
                    actionListener="#{relatorioHistoricoMB.executar}" />

                    <p:dataTable id="Grid" var="historico"
                        value="#{HistoricoBean.listaHistorico}"
                        selection="#{HistoricoBean.historico}" selectionMode="single"
                        rowKey="#{historico.idHistorico}" paginator="true" rows="5">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Historico" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:column headerText="Reservatorio">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Reservatorio" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{historico.reservatorio.nomeReservatorio}" />
                        </p:column>


                        <p:column headerText="Bomba">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Bomba" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{historico.bomba.nomeBomba}" />

                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Data">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Data" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{historico.dataHistorico}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Evento">
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="Evento" />
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{historico.novoStatusHistorico}" />
                        </p:column>


                    </p:dataTable>
                </h:form>
            </sec:ifAnyGranted>
        </div>
    </div>
</ui:define>
```

Bean:

```
@ManagedBean(name = "relatorioHistoricoMB")
@SessionScoped
public class RelatorioHistoricoMB {
    private Date dataInicial;
    private Date dataFinal;
    private Reservatorio reservatorio = new Reservatorio();
    private HistoricoCrudAnnotations historicoDAO = new HistoricoCrudAnnotations();
    private List<Reservatorio> listaReservatorio = new ArrayList<>();
    private ReservatorioCrudAnnotations reservatorioDAO = new ReservatorioCrudAnnotations();

    public void executar() throws Exception {
        List<Historico> ListaHistorico = new ArrayList<Historico>();

        HistoricoCrudAnnotations HistoricoDAO = new HistoricoCrudAnnotations();
        ListaHistorico = HistoricoDAO.listar();
        int x = ListaHistorico.size();
        Historico2[] ListaHistorico2 = new Historico2[x];
        List<Historico2> Historico = new ArrayList<Historico2>();
        GregorianCalendar dataCal = new GregorianCalendar();
        dataCal.setTime(dataInicial);
        int mesInicial = (dataCal.get(Calendar.MONTH))+1;
        dataCal.setTime(dataFinal);
        int mesFinal = (dataCal.get(Calendar.MONTH))+1;
        System.out.println("MÉTODO EXECUTAR");
        for (int i = 0; i < ListaHistorico.size(); i++) {
            String mesBanco = historicoDAO.listar().get(i).getDataHistorico()
                    .substring(3, 5);
            int mesBancoi = Integer.parseInt(mesBanco);
            System.out.println("Mês inicial: "+mesInicial);
            System.out.println("Mês Final: "+mesFinal);
            System.out.println("Mês Banco: "+mesBancoi);
            System.out.println("Reservatório: "+reservatorio.getIdReservatorio());
            System.out.println("Reservatório da lista: "+ListaHistorico.get(i).getReservatorio().getIdReservatorio());
            if ((mesBancoi >= mesInicial)
                    && (mesBancoi <= mesFinal)
                    && (reservatorio.getIdReservatorio() == ListaHistorico
                            .get(i).getReservatorio().getIdReservatorio()))

            {
                ListaHistorico2[i] = new Historico2();
                ListaHistorico2[i].setIdHistorico(ListaHistorico.get(i)
                        .getIdHistorico());
                ListaHistorico2[i].setNomeBomba(ListaHistorico.get(i)
                        .getBomba().getNomeBomba());
                ListaHistorico2[i].setNomeReservatorio(ListaHistorico.get(i)
                        .getReservatorio().getNomeReservatorio());
                ListaHistorico2[i].setNovoStatusHistorico(ListaHistorico.get(i)
                        .getNovoStatusHistorico());
                ListaHistorico2[i].setDataHistorico(ListaHistorico.get(i)
                        .getDataHistorico());
                ListaHistorico2[i].setObsReservatorio(ListaHistorico.get(i)
                        .getReservatorio().getObsReservatorio());
                Historico.add(ListaHistorico2[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("HISTORICO"+Historico.get(0).getNovoStatusHistorico());
        JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(
                Historico, false);
        Map<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Image logo = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Logo.png"))
                .getImage();
        parameterMap.put("logo", logo);
        ReportUtil.executarRelatorio("/WEB-INF/jasper/Rhistorico2.jasper",
                parameterMap, "RelatorioHistorico", beanCollectionDataSource);
    }
```

Bean: 
    @ManagedBean (name="MBReportUtil")
    @SessionScoped

```
public class ReportUtil {
     private static String ERRO_MENSAGEM_REPORT = "Um erro ocorreu quando o relatório estava sendo executado.";

        //executa o relatório através de um JRBeanCollectionDataSource
        public static void executarRelatorio(String caminhoRelatorio, Map<String, Object> parametros, String nomeRel, JRBeanCollectionDataSource fonteDados) throws Exception{

            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context.getExternalContext().getResponse();

            //pega o caminho do arquivo .jasper da aplicação
            InputStream reportStream = (InputStream) context.getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream(caminhoRelatorio);


            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+ nomeRel +".pdf");
            response.setContentType("application/download");
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            try {
                System.out.println("------Inicio Try!-------");     
                ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();


                //envia parametros para o relatório
                if (parametros == null){
                    parametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                }

                //envia para o navegador o PDF gerado
                JasperRunManager.runReportToPdfStream(reportStream, servletOutputStream, parametros, fonteDados);
                servletOutputStream.flush();
                servletOutputStream.close();

                System.out.println("-----Passou Flush e Close!-----");

            } catch (JRException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    throw new Exception(ERRO_MENSAGEM_REPORT);
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    throw new Exception(ERRO_MENSAGEM_REPORT);
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }finally{
                context.responseComplete();
            }
        }

        //executa o relatório através de uma Conexao
        public static void executarRelatorioConexao(String caminhoRelatorio, Map<String, Object> parametros, String nomeRel, java.sql.Connection connection) throws Exception{

            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context.getExternalContext().getResponse();

            //pega o caminho do arquivo .jasper da aplicação
            InputStream reportStream = (InputStream) context.getExternalContext().getResourceAsStream(caminhoRelatorio);


            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename="+ nomeRel +".pdf");
            response.setContentType("application/download");
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            try {
                System.out.println("------Inicio Try!-------");
                ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream();


                //envia parametros para o relatório
                if (parametros == null){
                    parametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                }

                //envia para o navegador o PDF gerado
                JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(caminhoRelatorio, parametros, connection);
                servletOutputStream.flush();
                servletOutputStream.close();

                System.out.println("-----Passou Flush e Close!-----");

            } catch (JRException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    throw new Exception(ERRO_MENSAGEM_REPORT);
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    throw new Exception(ERRO_MENSAGEM_REPORT);
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }finally{
                context.responseComplete();
            }
        }

}
```

Comment: Cara como você ta fazendo a consulta com os parâmetros passados?

Comment: historicoDAO.listar()

Comment: tá usando hibernate? onde está a query?

Comment: uso hibernate, um simples crud faz o que eu preciso.

Comment: Sim, mas pelo que vi você não está passando nenhum parâmetro pra sua consulta

Comment: Não entendi o que quer dizer, tudo que preciso é verificar se o historico presente no banco tem o reservatorio, data inicial e final iguais ao que foi  fornecido pelo usuário.